# How to block websites for a user, who has no root rights?

Tags: internet, root, users, websites, restricted-access

The situation is: I don‘t want to able to surf certain websites out of distraction of boredom, while I am in the University, studying.
My idea is:

1. Create a sudo-password which is to complex to memorize it, write in somewhere and leave it at home when I go to the University.
2. Create a user-account with restrictions, on the websites, which can be visited.
3. Study without distraction.

Comment: and you dont have any privileges on that user account ?

Comment: @Raja No, no privileges

Comment: @slobad if you have no privileges over that account, there is little chance you'll be able to do so.

Comment: @Anwar please have a look at my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that you can add *any* restrictions on other user accounts without being a super-user yourself. It's certainly not possible in Ubuntu's default and most other sane privilege management configurations.

Comment: I am sorry for not expressing myself precisely: I am the super-user but not on that account. The situation is: I don't want to be able to surf certain wegsites without the sudo-password. (Which i will make too complex to remember and leave it on a piece of paper at home when I go to university.)

Comment: So by "securely" you actually meant: too difficult/inconvenient to do out of distraction or boredom. That changes the problem *a lot*. Please amend your question to clarify that.

Comment: I edited the post. Hope it's better now. Thanks for your help.